# Getting unique values from a single column in a Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DataFrame

```
ID                               Source
 0                       52.109.120.107
 1        52.109.120.107, 223.30.22.236
 2                        223.30.22.236
 3        223.30.22.236, 52.109.120.107
 4        52.109.120.107, 223.30.22.236
```

Expected Output # 1

```
                                 Source
 0        223.30.22.236, 52.109.120.107
```

Expected Output # 2

```
               Source
0       223.30.22.236
1      52.109.120.107
```

Code I have tried

```
list = df['Source'].tolist()
set = set(list)
list2 = list(set)
```

Any Help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Question: `Source` is a `String` I suppose? And list2 is the result for one line of the DataFrame or for the entire DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, It is String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, we can use explode with some method chaining.

### 1

```
s = pd.Series(", ".join(df["Source"].str.split(",").explode().unique()))

print(s)

0    52.109.120.107, 223.30.22.236
dtype: object
```

---

### 2

```
s1 = pd.DataFrame({'Source' : (df["Source"].str.split(",").explode().unique())})

print(s1)
           Source
0  52.109.120.107
1   223.30.22.236
```

Answer (score 1):

please extend your code with

```
pd.DataFrame(data = list2,columns = ['Source'])
```